# Can not see nav bar and tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hi I'm trying to passing data from a view controller to a tablevievcontroller with a button but when i clicked to button only table view controller coming without nav and tab bar what can i do for this problem.

Here is my code

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import os.log


class informationViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var favbutton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var pName: UILabel!
   var obj = SearchTableViewController()



    @IBOutlet weak var history: UITextView!
     var historyStanbul : HistoricalPlace?
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        if let history1 = historyStanbul{

            navigationItem.title = history1.historyName


             pName.text = history1.historyName



            history.text = history1.information





        }


    }


    @IBAction func favButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let user = pName.text

        DispatchQueue.main.async(){

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "senddata", sender: self)

        }

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

            super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    /*    if let dest = segue.destination as? favTableViewController {
            if let name = sender as? String {
                dest.place.name = pName.text
                dest.place.information = history.text

             appDelegate.favplaces.append(dest.place)

            }

        }*/

        switch(segue.identifier ?? "") {

        case "senddata":
            guard let mealDetailViewController = segue.destination as? favTableViewController else {
                fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)")
            }


            let dest = segue.destination as? favTableViewController
            dest?.place.name = pName.text
            dest?.place.information = history.text

            appDelegate.favplaces.append((dest?.place)!)


        default:
            fatalError("Unexpected Segue Identifier; \(String(describing: segue.identifier))")
        }
    }










    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }





    }

 and here is my story board
```

[image]

pink marked tableviewcontroller which is my destination. Sender is vievcontroller which contains star inside itself

Comment: Not sure, but it looks to me that you are using too many navigation controllers. You might want only one as root for each tab bar tab.

Comment: You need to connect the segue from the view controller with the star to the navigation controller of the pink view controller. This should only solve the issue of not showing the nav bar. Passing the data is another problem.